# To be a scalar matrix or not to be?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What follows is a pretty (but not so easy) exercise. Is fun off-topic?

> Let $A, B \in M_2(\mathbb{C})$. Show that for every $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ $$((AB)^m-(BA)^m)((AB)^n-(BA)^n)$$ is a scalar matrix (that is, of the form $\lambda I_2$).

Comment: Asking questions to quiz other users is generally frowned upon.  I'm not sure about "off-topic", though.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know what trick you had in mind, but it is sufficient to note that $((AB)^m - (BA)^m)$ and $((AB)^n-(BA)^n)$ are commuting matrices, each with trace $0$.

Comment: Yes, it is the essential idea;

Comment: Yay! As long as we're having fun, then... suppose that the set of matrices $\{A_1,\dots,A_n\}$ forms a group under multiplication.  Show that 
$$
\operatorname{trace}\left( \sum_{j=1}^n A_j \right) = 0 \implies \sum_{j=1}^n A_j = 0
$$

Comment: Hint. $(\sum_jA_j)A_i=?$ and $trace((\sum_jA_j)^k)= ?$.

Comment: @loupblanc there you go

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure I follow your method.  You're doing something interesting here.

Comment: What I had in mind: note $(\sum_j A_j)^2 = n\sum_j A_j$

Comment: Yes, the mean $1/n\sum_jA_j$ is a projection. It is faster.

Comment: In fact, $1/\sqrt n \sum_j A_j$ is the projection