# Let $A,B \in {M_2}$ and $C=AB-BA$. Why is ${C^2} = \lambda I$ true?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B \in {M_2}$ and $C=AB-BA$. Why does ${C^2} = \lambda I$?

Comment: **Hint.** See the closely related question "http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1237361/to-be-a-scalar-matrix-or-not-to-be"

Comment: Have you covered the result that every matrix is a zero of its characteristic polynomial? Observe that $tr(AB-BA)=0$.

Comment: I performed a few minor grammatical edits to your post.  Hope it's OK.  Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

By Cayley-Hamilton we have $$C^2-tr(C)C+\det(C)I_2=0,$$ which gives $C^2=\lambda I_2$, because $tr(C)=tr(AB-BA)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

It is a well-known fact that for any two matrices $A$ and $B$ with

$C = [A, B] = AB - BA, \tag{1}$

we have

$\text{Tr} (C) = 0, \tag{2}$

where

$\text{Tr}(X) = \text{trace}(X) = X_{11} + X_{22} \tag{3}$

for any $2 \times 2$ matrix $X = [X_{ij}]$,  $1 \le i, j \le 2$.

It is also easy to verify (2) by direct calculation, especially in the $2 \times 2$ case (though it in fact holds for matrices of any size); with $A = [A_{ij}]$, $B = [B_{ij}]$, we have

$(AB)_{ii} = A_{i1}B_{1i} + A_{i2}B_{2i}; \tag{4}$

reversing the roles of $A$ and $B$ one writes

$(BA)_{ii} = B_{i1}A_{1i} + B_{i2}A_{2i}; \tag{5}$

if we now subtract (5) from (4) and sum over $i$, we find that all the terms of

$\text{Tr}([A, B]) = \sum_1^2 (AB - BA)_{ii} = \sum_1^2 ((AB)_{ii} - (BA)_{ii}) \tag{6}$

cancel out, leaving us with

$\text{Tr}([A, B]) = 0; \tag{7}$

incidentally, essentially the same argument works for any two  $n \times n$ matrices $A$, $B$.

That $\text{Tr}(C) = 0$ is the first piece of the puzzle; the second is provided by the Hamilton-Cayley theorem for $2 \times 2$ matrices, which asserts that $C$ satisfies the equation

$C^2 - \text{Tr}(C) + \det(C) I = 0; \tag{8}$

see [Proof that the characteristic polynomial of a $2 \times 2$ matrix is $x^2 - \text{tr}(A) x + \det (A)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1025418/proof-that-the-characteristic-polynomial-of-a-2-times-2-matrix-is-x2-tex) for a more detailed discussion.  Since $\text{Tr}(C) = 0$, (8) reduces to

$C^2 + \det(C) I = 0, \tag{9}$

or

$C^2 = -\det(C) I; \tag{10}$

taking $\lambda = -\det (C)$ in (10), we are done.